# Why don't LiPo charger chips isolate the output during shutdown?

Tags: battery-charging, boost

From what I've gathered, boost regulators from [MCP1640](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002234C.pdf) to [TPS61090](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61090.pdf) disconnect the load during shutdown so that the battery is not drained during shutdown.

However, charger chips like [BQ24295](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24295.pdf) don't seem to isolate the output during shutdown (at least I can't find it on the datasheet). If my reading is correct, why is the output not isolated? Don't charger chips face the same issue on this front as boost regulators do? It shouldn't be difficult to incorporate some shutdown logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading the [BQ24295 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24295.pdf) correctly, it can actually isolate the load from the battery.  It does this using an internal switch BATFET, which can be commanded through I<sup>2</sup>C to turn off (see section 8.3.1.2.1 in the datasheet).

[image]  (snippet from the functional diagram on p.14)

*p.s.* BQ24295 is a curious beast, because it can create a 5V supply for USB OTG from a single cell.

Comment: Interesting. Rather than `SYS`, I believe `PMID` is the boosted 5V output. I believe `SYS` goes up to 4.35V only. Indeed, the battery can be disconnected like you suggested, but I wonder if `PMID` could be isolated from the chip's circuitry. I think even with `BATFET` off, PMID is still connected to a whole bunch of other components. I'm asking because I wonder if there's a way to prevent the chip from frying if there's a small current (~300mA) at 5V comes in from `PMID`.

Comment: It looks like PMID is regulated separately. I don't think PMID can be active at the same time as VBUS. When VBUS is absent, Q4 will be on, and SYS will be at battery voltage. Then if PMID is neede, the inductor is used in a boost configuration boosting from SYS up to 5V at PMID.

Comment: I don't think you will fry anything inside the BQ24295. The absolute max on PMID is listed as 15V. When boost is enabled, it will attempt to regulate PMID to 5.1V. I do not know what effect that will have on other circuitry connected to PMID. But if you keep the boost function disabled, then I don't think you will have any problem. You should definitely get an evaluation board and try all this stuff. Also, try contacting TI. They have applications engineers to answer these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have thought this through. TI doesn't disconnect the battery from the load because if they did, the system would be completely de-energized. Normal battery powered systems have real-time clocks and various low-power circuits that operate even when the device is "off." At a minimum, there is some circuitry monitoring the power button to detect when it is pressed so that the system can boot back up. If that circuitry is de-energized, the whole system is latched off and can't recover.

Comment: But doesn't this argument apply to those boost regulators that isolate the load during shutdown as well? Wouldn't the circuitry be de-energised?

Comment: Typically, there is an "alive" regulator that supplies power to the real-time clock and the power button detect circuit. That regulator would never be disabled. But other regulators might be, to save power. Disconnecting the battery from the alive regulator would brick the system until/unless somehow the state was reset (maybe by USB insertion or something). Other regulators might be disabled by the processor to save power. These could be re-enabled as part of the boot-up process.

Comment: @mkeith  Shipping mode (8.3.1.2.2 in the datasheet).  20uA quiescent consumption in that shipping mode, though.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, yeah. I see that now, too. But that is something you can only do by issuing an I2C command. Before you do that, you need to make sure there is a reasonable way out of shipping mode for the customer. Sending an I2C command will not be possible if the processor is powered from SYS, obviously, so you have to use one of the other methods. And 200 uA is kind of disappointing, but OK, I guess, if your battery is large.